# How To Delete Cookie Name _ga of OneTrust

Tags: one-trust

The Website is using OneTrust, when popup cookie setting show then generated _ga cookie name.
Client want to when click button Reject all on popup cookie setting then delete _ga cookie name.
But I think delete cookie name _ga is behavior of OneTrust or I've to use Jquery to delete cookie name _ga

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: have you enabled auto-blocking? have you implemented the script before any other script loaded?